# Can't import class to another class, won't even know it exists

Tags: java, class

I was watching [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/wT9uNGzMEM4?t=150) and that import suggestion doesn't show up and when i add it manually it says "***The constructor Player(KeyHandler) is undefined***" but for him it works normally, so im guessing something is wrong on my end.

[This is how my problem looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEClf.png) and [this is the other class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPB7U.png) and [this is manually imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSy6G.png).

Keep in mind i am new to programing, sorry if i posed the question wrong.

Comment: You need to `import entity.Player;` into `GamePanel`

Comment: Your issue is a typo. You forgot to pass the first argument (`this` via `GamePanel`) into the `Person` class that expects it as the first argument.

Comment: If i knew how to recreate the code i would not be here. Thank you for your time anyway, and thank you to those who actually gave me answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the "This is manually imported" solution is that the constructor for Player.java requires GamePanel and KeyHandler as the argument but you are passing only KeyHandler object in the solution. I will suggest you to add "," between this and keyH so the code looks like:

```
Player player = new Player(this, keyH);
```